# Ways to enable communication between kerberized and non kerberized environments

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

We have a non Kerberized Hortonworks cluster which needs to access services in a [Kerberized Cloudera cluster](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/sg_auth_overview.html).

Which are the ways in which the non Kerberized cluster can communicate with the kerberized cluster?

Can we

- Configure the KDC in the Kerberized cluster to be the common KDC?
- [Kerberize the Hortonworks cluster](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_security/content/configuring_amb_hdp_for_kerberos.html) by installing and configuring Kerberos, create SPNs and UPNs etc.,?

Comment: In other words, the unsecure cluster runs **client** jobs that access the secure cluster? Just like you would run a test job on your PC, except that it's distributed via MR or Tez or Spark? Please be more specific, w/ examples.

Answer (score 1):

"Which are the ways in which the non Kerberized cluster can communicate with the kerberized cluster" generally there are none (with exceptions -see below) .. once you kerberize a cluster, it becomes a "secure" cluster that would require Kerberos authentication to talk to many of that cluster resources. If another (source) cluster where you're making requests is not kerberized, it'll not even have a kerberos ticket to authenticate in the other cluster.

Although certain services can control authentication separately. For `HBase`, those are `hbase.security.authentication` and `hbase.rest.authentication.type` (each one can be `simple` or `kerberos`). Which ones you're trying to use? Hive doesn't have an equivalent for these HBase settings. Solr does, for example, see "Solr Secure Authentication". Etc (I didn't go through all services)

So certain things can be relaxed for authentication, but it would be for all access not just from that non-kerberized cluster.

What you're looking for might need custom application in between if you'd like to have access from a non-secure to a secure cluster.